# How to toggle two fragments in one activity?

Tags: java, android, xml, android-fragments

I have two `fragment` classes and two buttons in the application bar - each button is doing one of the following:

1. check if a `fragment` from the other classes exists
2. if exists, replace the container with new instance of his `fragment` class
3. if not exists create new instance of his `fragment` class

Here is the sample code:

```
private void openReader() {

    FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();

    ArticleListFragment fragmentList = (ArticleListFragment) fragmentManager.findFragmentById(R.id.action_list);
    ArticleReaderFragment fragmentReader = (ArticleReaderFragment) fragmentManager.findFragmentById(R.id.action_reader);

    if (fragmentReader==null || ! fragmentReader.isInLayout()) {

        if (fragmentList==null || ! fragmentList.isInLayout()) {

            FragmentTransaction ft = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
            ft.add(R.id.container_id, new ArticleReaderFragment());
            //ft.addToBackStack(null);
            ft.commit();

        } else {

            FragmentTransaction ft = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
            ft.replace(R.id.container_id, new ArticleReaderFragment());
            //ft.addToBackStack(null);
            ft.commit();

        }
    }
    else {
        // fragment.update(...);
    }

}
```

and here is the `activity` XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/welcome_page">

    <FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/container_id">

    </FrameLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

The issue is that the `replace` function is not `destroying` the old `fragment` class - it is adding more and more fragments over each other as the buttons are clicked.

Could anyone tell what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have made a lot of mistakes:

1. I did not specified the ID of the fragments
2. Since I am not able to set a fragment ID dynamically, I need to use a tag instead

   ```
   ft.replace(R.id.container_id, new ArticleListFragment(), "Action_list");
   ```

   or

   ```
   ft.add(R.id.container_id, new ArticleListFragment(), "Action_list");
   ```
3. I need to use only `findFragmentByTag()` as `isInLayout()` is always giving me false.

Here is the working version of the function:

```
private void openList() {

        FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();

        ArticleListFragment fragmentList = (ArticleListFragment) fragmentManager.findFragmentByTag("Action_list");
        ArticleReaderFragment fragmentReader = (ArticleReaderFragment) fragmentManager.findFragmentByTag("Action_reader");

        if (fragmentList==null) {

            if (fragmentReader==null) {

                FragmentTransaction ft = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
                ft.add(R.id.container_id, new ArticleListFragment(), "Action_list");
                //ft.addToBackStack(null);
                ft.commit();

            } else {

                FragmentTransaction ft = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
                ft.replace(R.id.container_id, new ArticleListFragment(), "Action_list");
                //ft.addToBackStack(null);
                ft.commit();

            }
        }
        else {
            // fragment.update(...);
        }
    }
```